# What are all the possible ways to achieve acoustic resonance in a cavity?

Tags: acoustics, resonance, models

If one were to observe acoustic resonance in a cavity (semi-closed volume of space) what is the complete list of potential hypotheses as to the cause?

In my limited experience I can list the following

- Helmholtz resonance: requires a 'belly'and 'neck' that facilitate lumped 
  influences of compliance and intertance
- Standing wave: interference between reflected waves, so usually
  requires a somewhat straight channel, reflecting boundaries
- Aeroelastic flutter: requires a boundary that shears an incoming flow, spins
  off eddies or oscillating regions of pressure that in turn impose reaction 
  forces that vibrate the structure

Any other possible physical structures one can consider that could lead to resonance?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a cavity but another example is the tuning fork, the 2 prongs come into resonance, creating a standing wave in the middle of the prongs which travels down through the handle (not damping the oscillation at first look)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all systems with finite dimensions can exhibit resonant behaviour, which will depend on their geometry and boundary conditions. The Helmholtz resonator and standing waves you describe are in fact based on the same principle.

It is customary to treat the Helmholtz resonator with lumped elements. It is easy to see that since the shape of the volume is not specified in this case, you could very well treat the volume as a rigidly terminated duct supporting only plane waves (a valid assumption in the lowest frequency range and the reason lumped elements can be used) you could end up with the same behaviour of a resonant system excited by a source with the characteristics of the neck. Based on the dimensions of the neck, a piston with the shape of the cross-section of the neck can be assumed with a specific volume velocity. Thus, you can see that in practice, at least the two first cases kind of describe the same phenomenon but from different “viewpoints” (different formulations).

To conclude, I believe that all open-closed (or semi-open, or semi-closed) systems (cavities in a sense) have natural modes, which when excited will result in a resonant behaviour. All it comes down to is to excite the systems at one of these natural frequencies (please not that these may change a bit based on the “loading” of the excitation source).